# CMS Page not found - redirect to startpage - Django

Tags: django

My website is entirely a cms-based website. for example `/de/` page has 2 cms apphooks, news and videos, and `/en/` only videos page.

```
http://blabla.com/de/videos/funny-video/98/
```

If i change the above working url to

```
http://blabla.com/en/news/funny-news/100/
```

I am getting:

```
Page not found (404)
```

the reasion is obvious. en website doesnot have news page.

I want a redirect to startpage if this 404 happens. i tried:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  
  url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
  url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/', permanent=False)), # <---
)
```

but now:

```
CMS Page not found:
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to get this straight: `'/'` really has an appropriate view?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall ``/`` is just a startpage's url which has a view, yes.

Comment: Alright. I guess overriding the default 404 view is not an option?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall 404handler is problematic, because all pages are hooks, i am not sure if it works with it